# MySQL join query - Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql

What could be wrong with this one? I am getting Error #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'v'

```
SELECT v.newsid AS identifier, j.createdate AS DATE, j.newstext AS TEXT, j.uuid AS user, j.flags AS fcount, j.votes AS vcount, j.authornick AS nick 
FROM votes v 
INNER JOIN news v ON j.newsid = v.newsid GROUP BY v.newsid ORDER BY COUNT( v.newsid )   
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: You are using the alias v for both votes and the news table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot use the same table alias multiple times. You are associated `v` with `votes` and table `news`.

Change your query and alias references to something like

```
SELECT .....
FROM votes v 
INNER JOIN news n ON ....
               ^^^ <=== Change this to something else
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the news table's alias should be "j". You have used "j.newsid = v.newsid" in join statement